# Was there an Evans & Sutherland display system capable of rendering ordinary data as motion through a landscape?

Tags: graphics

Around 1987, the investment bank I worked for had a high-end graphics device, possibly from Evans & Sutherland, which produced an "animated" display not unlike the view from the front seat of the first car of a roller coaster. Here it was possible to "ride the graph" given a time series of stock prices of IBM or whatever. As such, this device was used solely for demonstration.

Would anyone know what device this could have been or if any pictures or videos exist of its output?

Comment: In the late 80's a number of companies, including Evans & Sutherland and SiliconGraphics, had graphics terminals capable of rendering a 3D display such as you describe. I don't think without more specifics it would be possible to actually answer your question, as it's entirely possible any one of those might have been configured for such a demo.

Comment: Was it a computer generated 3D image or was it video frames from an actual recording?

Comment: When the Shuttle Mission Simulator upgraded from its original bespoke out-the-window graphics generators (Link Flight Simulation proprietary DIGs), they went to an Evans and Sutherland system. This would have been in the early 90s.  I will see if I have any actual info on the systems.

Answer (score 1):

Look for Evans & Sutherland PS300 and decide whether this is the unit you remember.  There were other models (PS350?) later.  The timing (1987) is about right.

http://computergraphmuseum.free.fr/evans.htm

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5QUvyA1VJmk